# MySQL date field contains no value - having problem importing

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm migrating some data into MySQL and the dump from the other database has left a particular date field blank.

The table looks like this:

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| lngID            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0          |       |
| dtmDateSubmitted | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 |       |
```

This insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblReports VALUES (1012,'', ...
```

The date field which got dumped for a large number of the records is null but represented as: `''`.

I'm getting the following error when trying to import this:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 1: 
Incorrect date value: '' for column 'dtmDateSubmitted' at row 1
```

Am feeling a bit dumb because really I've never understood the null/blank deal properly and the docs are killing me.

Is it that 'date' fields in MySQL doesn't allow `''` values under any circumstances? It needs to be `NULL`? (For the record I've tried a stack of combinations between the null and default options to no avail).

Normally I'd change `''` to `NULL` to make this error go away but it seems so wrong and hackish. Can anybody tell me what a proper/better way to treat this is?

I suspect I could be fundamentally misunderstanding the way MySQL works, and replacing `''` with `NULL` *is* the proper way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Alter your datetime column to varchar.
- Import sql.
- `Update tbl set dtmDateSubmitted=NULL where dtmDateSubmitted='';`
- Alter column back to datetime.

Comment: That assumes that the column accepts null values.  Best practice is to perform as few DML operations as possible.

Comment: just replace null with any value you want, anyway it's empty string in original insert. what would you insert instead??

Comment: fantastic soluiton. In SQL, NULL != NODATE. That's the zero value for. NULL = unknown value while 0 date value or '' means: have no value. Also the question is about ease the import. Kane solution is brillant in being consistent on have 0 date value instead of NULL and also make import piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblReports (lngID) VALUES (1012)
```

Should use the default value for the `dtmDateSubmitted` column. So just don't include that column in your insert statements.

Comment: There are more than 10K records and I'm reluctant to either man-handle  the INSERT bit or go back to the client - I sincerely hoping this can be resolved by changing the schema. 

Though if it has to be, it has to be.

Comment: Also there are 20 other fields in this table that I didn't include in the example for obvious reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

So, how *are* you inserting the data? By executing SQL statements or programmatically through something like PHP (which generates the insert statements for you)?

Either way, something has to be done about those '' inserted into the date fields and Aistina's suggestion is a good one.

The problem is that '' is just not a valid date and the error would be inevitable.

Could you do a bulk edit of the SQL statements, if that's your method?

Maybe using regular expressions.

Changing the schema would surely cause problems when extracting data - it wouldn't be the format extracted before the change.

Comment: Directly into MySQL. I have a data.sql that I'm putting into mysql through shell like this: 
> mysql -ume -ppass mydb < data.sql
 | I've never done bulk edits though could be a good time to learn.

Comment: Yes, Aistina's INSERT statement, with the missing '' right after the lngID value shouldn't be too difficult to edit (*famous last words*)

Comment: BTW, I didn't mean I wasn't going to say any more about the question, I meant that I might be tempting fate to say 'shouldn't be too difficult to edit'